# The type or namespace name 'Key' could not be found

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The [Key] attribute for entity framework is not working for me.  I have a `console` application and I am trying to add this class:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int IDPost { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int IDBlog { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

I get these errors:

> The type or namespace name 'Key' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'KeyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have added this using:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

And I have these references added to the project:

```
EntityFramework
EntityFramework.SqlServer
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

I am using EF6 and VS2012.

What reference am I missing?

Comment: Put your cursor on `Key`, hit Ctrl + period. If a menu appears, choose the option to add the `using` statement.

Comment: Ahh bingo.  Thank you very much.  I needed "using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In EF6, System.Data.Entity has been replaced with System.Data.Entity.Core.  Make sure that you are no longer referencing any EF5 dlls and replace your using inclusion with

```
System.Data.Entity.Core
```

In addition, `[Key]` comes from the

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

namespace.  If you have it included in the using statements for your class, it should compile.

Answer (score 1):

For myself I had a lowercase [key] instead of [Key], so be sure to check for this when you come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error using Visual Studio 2010 when I was creating an asp.net Webforms application. I followed these steps and it worked for me.

1. open nugetpackage manager and search System.data.entity.
2. install it.
3. put reference of using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, it was because the project wasn't saved.